# Is pointer arithmetic on allocated storage allowed since C++20?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, lifetime, c++20

In the C++20 standard, it is said that array types are *implicit lifetime type*.

Does it mean that an array to a non implicit lifetime type can be implicitly created? The implicit creation of such an array would not cause creation of the array's elements?

Consider this case:

```
//implicit creation of an array of std::string 
//but not the std::string elements:
void * ptr = operator new(sizeof (std::string) * 10);
//use launder to get a "pointer to object" (which object?)
std::string * sptr = std::launder(static_cast<std::string*>(ptr));
//pointer arithmetic on not created array elements well defined?
new (sptr+1) std::string("second element");
```

Is this code not UB any more since C++20?

---

Maybe this way is better?

```
//implicit creation of an array of std::string 
//but not the std::string elements:
void * ptr = operator new(sizeof (std::string) * 10);
//use launder to get a "pointer to object" (actually not necessary)
std::string (* sptr)[10] = std::launder(static_cast<std::string(*)[10]>(ptr));
//pointer arithmetic on an array is well defined
new (*sptr+1) std::string("second element");
```

---

**TC Answer + Comments conclusion:**

1. Array elements are not created but the array is created
2. The use of `launder` in the first example cause UB, and is
   not necessary in the second example.

The right code is:

```
    //implicit creation of an array of std::string 
    //but not the std::string elements:
    void * ptr = operator new(sizeof (std::string) * 10);
    //the pointer already points to the implicitly created object
    //so casting is enough 
    std::string (* sptr)[10] = static_cast<std::string(*)[10]>(ptr);
    //pointer arithmetic on an array is well defined
    new (*sptr+1) std::string("second element");
```

Comment: I've just done a search through the (draft) C++20 standard, and found nothing that describes arrays as an "implicit lifetime type" (and, yes, I searched for variations).   Please provide a more detailed description of your claim (e.g.  section and clause in the standard).   Bit hard to answer your question without being able to find the source, let alone any relevant context.

Comment: @Peter: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#9, last sentence

Comment: I was looking at the PDF http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf (ostensibly the latest working draft) and it doesn't even have that sentence.    Looks like you'll need to find the meaning of "implicit-lifetime" too.   I suspect your link may have picked up some "edits in progress" that haven't even made it into released working drafts.

Comment: @Peter The changes are the result of [P0593](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/106) being merged into the standard from the recent Prague meeting. They haven't yet released the resulting draft yet, but you can see the merged wording [in this commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3765/commits/f6c2987ffa70ee1efc9bee65fed06d891b3d6a5d).

Comment: @Oliv  where's the quote says that "void * ptr = operator new(sizeof (std::string) * 10);" will create  an **array** of type std::string? [expr.new] does not say that.

Comment: @Oliv According to the comments in the answer, std::launder is not necessary in the second version and causes UB in the first version. May be edit needed to make the code valid?
It is still not 100% percent clear which version is correct - if both, perhaps state that explicitly or in the answer and also clarify which version is "idiomatic"?

Comment: @YuvalK Did it. Fill free to improve the added conclusion.

Comment: @Oliv - just want to clarify. Does it mean that first option is not correct? Or since an array of `std::string` is created, the language allows to deduce that `static_cast<std::string*>` points to the first element of the array and not just random string? Or only the second variant is valid?

Comment: @YuvalK The first is not correct because of `std::launder`. Without `std::launder` it would be correct.

Comment: @Oliv - `std::string (* sptr)[10] = static_cast<std::string(*)[10]>(ptr);` is that it doesn't scale if you want to replace 10 with n - in order to dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: @YuvalK Yes in case of dynamic memory allocation size this line should be replaced by `std::string * sptr = static_cast<std::string *>(ptr)`

Comment: Now, what happens if you use placement new, as in the example of allocate(n) in the standard? https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#general-2
`launder(reinterpret_­cast<T*>(new (p) byte[n * sizeof(T)]))` is not a legal use of launder according to the comments to the answer (no T is created...). On the other hand, you run into problems without `launder` either, as far as I know. 
Standard is not clear whether `launder` can be used to `legalize` pointer arithmetic - as far as I am aware it doesn't state that.

Comment: @YuvalK Could this example predate C++20?

Comment: No. It appears in p0593r6 as well, as one of the suggested changes.
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#16535-table-34-cpp17allocator-requirements-tabcpp17allocator. The code snippet is new.

Comment: @YukalK `allocate(n)` would not produce a *a pointer to a suitable created object.* but `malloc` would do?

Comment: When did someone say that?

Comment: @YuvalK Nobody probably. allocate(n) return a pointer to suitably allocated object, The exemple given in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#16535-table-34-cpp17allocator-requirements-tabcpp17allocator show how to reuse storage, but not how to use the resulting pointer of the allocation function. This is common in the c++ standard, examples are not used to illustrate the specification but to show how brilliant is the author when he faces unrelated corner case.

Comment: My impression, that it was an example of "how allocate(n) might be implemented" - as these are requirements *allocator requirements*. This is not an issue for the standard `std::allocator<T>` - they are allowed to be "magic" and "implementation defined".

Comment: @YuvalK The exemple begin with "Example: When **reusing storage** denoted by some pointer value p". **reusing storage** is defined in basic/lifetime. The first use of the pointer return by allocate(n) is not a storage result. For a storage to be reused it must be occupied by an alived object (and not be an array of byte type or unsigned char type => see basic/object). I think the standard lacks editorials constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it means that an array to a non implicit lifetime type can be implicitly created?

Yes.

> The implicit creation of such an array would not cause creation of the array's elements?

Yes.

This is what makes `std::vector` implementable in ordinary C++.

Comment: Could you confirm also that `std::launder(static_cast<std::string*>(ptr))` does not return a pointer to the first element of the array because it is not within its lifetime, but that `std::launder(static_cast<std::string(*)[10]>(ptr))` return a pointer to the array, because the array is within its lifetime?

Comment: @Oliv And I suppose the `std::launder` isn't actually needed, because https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#11 guarantees that `ptr` will already point to the array?

Comment: @walnut, I missed that. So a `static_cast` to `std::string (*) [10]` should be sufficient! tx.

Comment: @Oliv But I guess the question then becomes whether your first example without the `std::launder` will be well-defined. There is no `std::string` object to point to, but `ptr` could point to the array, so that the static cast will leave the value unchanged and `sptr` will point to the array as well. With `std::launder` it is UB simply because of `std::launder`'s requirements.

Comment: @walnut Indeed, the necessity of this circumvolution was `std::launder`. Cool that makes the code much more readable.

Comment: Does it mean that both `std::string * sptr = static_cast<std::string*>(ptr)` and `std::string (* sptr)[10] = static_cast<std::string(*)[10]>(ptr)` are valid? Or only the `static_cast<std::string(*)[10]>(ptr)` version? If both are valid, which one is preferred?