# Is it safe in C++ to derive a pointer from std::aligned_storage before using it?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, language-lawyer, c++20

Is it guaranteed to be safe by the C++ standard to derive a pointer to `T` from `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>` before the `T` itself is actually created? For example, is the following legal?

```cpp
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> storage;
T* ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage);  // Perhaps with std::launder?
new (&storage) T;

ptr->DoSomething();
```

I would appreciate references to the standard about why this is allowed/not allowed. I'm writing in C++17, but would still be interested if the answer is different in C++20.

The reason I want this to be legal is to efficiently implement a pair of promise/future types, with covariance in the value type (so `Future<Animal>` can be constructed from `Promise<Cat>`). Here is a sketch of what that might look like, with all the SFINAE and synchronization and other details stripped:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Promise {
  private:
   // The storage in which we'll eventually construct our object once SetValue
   // is called. We don't just use a T object directly because we don't want
   // to require it to be default-constructible.
   std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> storage_;
   
   // Does storage_ contain a value yet?
   bool ready_ = false;
   
  public:
   void SetValue(T value) {
    new (&storage_) T(std::move(value));
    ready_ = true;
   }
};

template <typename T>
class Future {
  private:
   // A pointer that will eventually be valid.
   const T* const ptr_;

  public:
   // Create a future that can be used to access the value set on the supplied
   // promise.
   //
   // REQUIRES: U is T, or a subclass of T.
   template <typename U>
   Future(Promise<U>* promise)
       : ptr_(reinterpret_cast<U>(promise->storage_)) {}
   
   // REQUIRES: Promise::SetValue has been called.
   const T& Get() const { return *ptr_; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this basically what `std::vector` does? It stores the pointer to the allocated memory (the equivalent of your `ptr`), then creates objects there, and finally accesses the objects through this pointer. But yes, implementability of `std::vector` is questionable (IIRC, there was some change in C++20 in this regard).

Comment: Yeah, `std::vector` would need to do it too. But as part of the standard library it has special dispensation as I understand it: it can use compiler intrinsics or whatever; it doesn't need to be portable itself. I'm looking for a portable way to do it on top of the standard, not from within the standard, if that makes sense.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1413r2.pdf

Comment: P1413R2 is an interesting paper for context (thanks), but I don't think it answers my question. I can imagine that https://stackoverflow.com/q/60631224 can be used to answer my question, but it would take an expert to see how and I can't quite put the pieces together. I also asked for references to the standard, which https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639590/1505451 does not provide.